# How to fire "Select" event on google line chart?

Tags: google-visualization

I want to trigger "Select" event on line chart load. I use 
*my_chart.setSelection([{row: row_number, column: column_number}]);* on document load, and it works good. But it doesn't fire up my handler function *google.visualization.events.addListener(my_chart, 'select', function() {...});*. Which is my goal. Please, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the same function when the `'ready'` event fires...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      540]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
    
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', selectHandler);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
    
    chart.draw(data, {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    });
    
    function selectHandler() {
      chart.setSelection([{row: 0, column: 1}]);
    }
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="curve_chart"></div>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Damn, that was pretty obvious)